# Doesn't Lua have something comparable to Ruby's method_missing?

Tags: ruby, lua, metaprogramming, method-missing

I seem to recall Lua has something similar to Ruby's method_missing.  Or am I remembering incorrectly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `__index` and `__newindex` of a table's [metatable](http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.2.html) can be used to the same effect as Ruby's `method_missing`.

Comment: Yes, upon more vigilant googling I found this URL http://www.lua.org/pil/13.4.1.html from the Lua manual which states: "when we access an absent field in a table .... such access triggers the interpreter to look for an __index metamethod"